# How to remove a part of a URL argument string in php

Tags: php, string

Why does this not remove the `example/` :

```
$url = "http://webserver/exmaple/subdomaine/";
$domaine="example"
$domaine= $domaine."/";
echo str_replace($domaine,"",$url);
```

Is there a better way to do so ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$domaine = "example"; // Missing semicolon ...
```

Comment: And what about the typo?

Answer (score 0):

Check spelling:

`exmaple` !== `example`

**exmaple** would be a tree that was a maple in the past but is now another type of tree such as an oak or yew.

Answer (score 0):

did a mistake here

```
$domaine="example"
```

replace it by

```
$domaine="example";
```

Comment: Difference from my post !